# H-Bridge current limiting

Tags: dc-motor, h-bridge, surge-protection

I am designing a simple H bridge circuit for use with the Atmega8 microcontroller. The DC motor moves this application a lot and generates 140 mA current spikes (DC motor locked) or 60 mA with normal workload.

The working voltage ranges from 10 to 16 V, I will use the transistors BD441 / BD442 (2 A of DC current at 20 V and 4 A DC at 10 V) were the most robust that will fit in my circuit.

[image: H-Bridge with current limit]

Q1 to Q5 will be BD441 / 442, some questions:

- Q5 through R8 (shunt) limits the current (I will leave 200ma peak), it makes sense to use this transistor to limit the inductive current peaks or I could just limit the current through the base of the transistors? What would be the problem of operating the base current transistor to operate in a linear region up to 200 mA?
- Q6 will be a small npn, together with a 20 V zener it makes Q5 cut and stops driving in cases of over voltage. I've seen this DC motor being operated by a transistor with 45 Vce without fail, I wanted more robustness in the circuit, does it make sense to use it or not?
- Use small resistors (0R33, 0R66 etc.) in the DC motor terminals help protect the circuit against very short surge currents that the oscilloscope cannot see or does my 4 ohm rshunt resistor solve this already?

Comment: Reduce the components man. There’s Hundreds of half bridge IC, and Motor drivers. That Gigantic BD135 will consume a lot of space and PCB will cost more money.

Comment: And for surge protection you may use transient Suppression diodes. But first simplify your circuit.

Comment: In my country it is difficult to find these IC's, expensive and most of the times of poor quality. BD's transistors I can buy originals and at great prices, I want to work even on protection of the circuit, in the future I intend to replace the transistors with automotive mosfets. About using transient protection diodes, I even thought about using MOV varistor because I think it's easy too

Comment: @Marcelo Farnell, Digi-Key and Mouser ships all over the world.

Comment: Brother, china is still on planet earth. If you have a low budget please search in Aliexpress.